# How to Increase the performance in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, moss

I writing the custom code(webparts) which deals with the data(list/libraries) in the sharepoint.. i would like to know all the tips that will increase the performance...
for eg: using of foreach in unwanted loops(we can use SPQuery insted)..

Please give me the tips which increase the performance of webpart and sharepoint site.
also all the threshhold limits for sharepoint ..

Comment: How much data are we talking about? Ie how many list items?

Comment: Say if document library having 1500 folders and in that again 1500 sub folders in that we have 100 documents in each folder..i need one document in 1292 folder in that 205 subfolder 98th document...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice series on SharePoint 2010 performance that may help you get started:

http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/12/18/sp-2010-developing-for-performance-part-1-developer-dashboard.aspx

It will give you idea on basic tools available with SharePoint.

Though I do not think there is a definite answer to what you are looking for. Performance tuning is an Art, there is no defined method you can use. It is always lot of things and factor you have to look into.

Good Luck!